# kendo ui - change datasource on tab change

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm, kendo-tabstrip

I've a kendo ui tabstrip on a page. Each page has to display grid from different datasources. I am using `kendo-mvvm` pattern.

```
var customderDetails = kendo.observable({
            // properties of customer-details
        // how do i different datasources on tab change 
    });
kendo.bind($('#addCustomerDetailsContent'), customderDetails);
```

`addCustomerDetailsContent` has tabstrip with 5 tabs.

**How do I change datasource on tab change of tabstrip ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ir order to change the `DataSource` of `Grid` you should use `setDataSource` method:

```
grid.setDataSource(new_datasource);
```

In order to detect tab change, you should bind your handler to `activate` event on `TabStrip`

So, it should be something like:

```
$("#tabs").kendoTabStrip({
    activate: function (e) {
        // Compute new DataSource for this tab
        var aux = ...
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(aux);
    }
}).data("kendoTabStrip");
```

In the following JSFiddle I show how to switch a grid that is outside the tab: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6Cuyr/

**BUT** there is the question -not clear on your original question- if the grid is the tab or not. If it is actually in the tab, I would recommend having as many different grids as tabs and then you do not have to switch datasource (there is always a price associated with setting a new datasource) and then you can do something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" data-role="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li>ds1</li>
        <li>ds2</li>
        <li>ds3</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div data-role="grid" data-bind="source: ds1"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div data-role="grid" data-bind="source: ds2"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div data-role="grid" data-bind="source: ds3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i.e. Define that the content of the `TabStrip` is a `Grid` and bind it to the member of you model that contains the datasource for that tab (`data-bind="source: ds1">`).

Then, the JavaScript would be:

```
var mvvm = kendo.observable({
    ds1 : new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data    : ...
    }),
    ds2: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data    : ...
    }),
    ds3 : new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data    : ...
    })
});

// Bind TabStrip to our observable object mvvm
kendo.bind($("#tabs"), mvvm);
```

You can see it in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6Cuyr/3/